# SQL Server Alert System: 'Severity 17 - Potentially Fatal Error Insufficient Resources' occurred on myserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, error-log, alerts

I get a alert email with the title:

> SQL Server Alert System: 'Severity 17 - Potentially Fatal Error
>   Insufficient Resources' occurred on myserver as 12:02

when I connect to myserver to check the log
I see the below:

[image]

we are on sql server 2005.

and I am not sure what this local connection provider is.

any hints?

Comment: Is this server used for anything else? Looks like it's being forced to use the page file rather than memory. FYI, that's a named pipe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175579/what-are-named-pipes

Comment: What patch level you are running for sql server 2005 ?

Comment: @Kin from the screen shot looks like SP4 (bottom right corner).

Comment: You might also review this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/05/12/sql-server-reports-working-set-trim-warning-message-during-early-startup-phase.aspx  This discusses start-up warnings and warnings that can occur later.  Quoting: "So before spending a lot of time investigating why this is happening, please look at the values for the Working Set and committed memory."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an error due to memory pressure.

#### Analysis

The errors in your screen shot are sequentially starting from the bottom and then ending at the top. This unfolds as follows:

- Your SQL Server instance is coming under pressure due to a possibly low setting of the `max server memory (MB)` configuration setting. These are the memory errors.
- Because you have a low memory setting or unavailable memory, the Named Pipes connection that was opened under the instance crashes.
- The Named Pipes protocol for the instance has to be reinitialised.
- This triggers the FATAL Error message.

I am basing my analysis on the error log and the following excerpt from the Microsoft SQL Server Documentation:

> Named Pipes is a protocol developed for local area networks. **A part of memory is used by one process to pass information to another process**, so that the output of one is the input of the other. The second process can be local (on the same computer as the first) or remote (on a networked computer).

<sup>***Reference:** [Choosing a Network Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2016/ms187892(v=sql.130)) (Microsoft | Docs)*</sup>

**The Named Pipes connection crashes and has to be reinitialised due to low available memory.**

#### Solution

Increase the amount of memory for your SQL Server instance and/or the underlying Windows Server.

#### Reference Reading

- [Server memory configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | Docs)